# Multiple instances in loop

Tags: java, list, loops, instance

How can I create an instance for each object in a list?

I am using a loop to store the values of this object but when I access these objects they are all the same, I want them to be different.

In this case, I have two challenges in "registeredChallenges" and I want the int progress and boolean completed to be different when I change them, how I can do that

**Ex:**
***Challenge1:*** Progress 1 and Completed false - ***Challenge2:*** Progress 5 and Completed true

Thank you!

```
List<Challenge> registeredChallenges = plugin.getChallengeRegistry().getRegisteredChallenges(ChallengeType.COLLECT);
for (Challenge challenge : registeredChallenges) {
    ChallengeHolder challengeHolder = new ChallengeHolder(challenge, 0, false);
    if (!challengeHolder.isCompleted()) {
        int challengeCondition = challenge.getChallengeCondition();
        if (challengeHolder.getProgress() < challengeCondition) {
            challengeHolder.setProgress(challengeHolder.getProgress() + 1);
        }
        int challengeRemaining = plugin.getDatabaseManager().getChallengeRemaining(playerUUID, challenge);
        if (challengeHolder.getProgress() >= challengeCondition) {
            challengeHolder.setCompleted(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate how you mean: *to be different when I change them*. How should the change appear?

Comment: @Grim I put an example above, maybe it is not very clear. Considering that the conditions are fulfilled until the end, "challengeHolder.setCompleted(true)" is changing the boolean in the ChallengeHolder class but it is changed for each object in the list when I only want it to be changed for the object that reached the end.

Each object has different conditions so none of them can be the same, I don't know if I'm explaining this correctly.

Comment: Well, the explination Id expected is like this: "The user starts the application. The user see the menu in the console. The user print a list of registered challenges. The list contains two elements. The user select the first registreredchallange. The application asks what to modify, progress or completition. The user selects the progress and enter a 5. Then the application changes the progress of the first challange to 5. ..."

Comment: That's correct, but when I run it with the code above, the progress (5) changes for the two challenges (or the all challenges in the list). When the list has only one challenge there is no problem, but when there are two challenges  I don't know how to change the progress only for the challenge that fulfills all the conditions.

Comment: You need to show the code of `Challenge` /  `ChallengeHolder` classes.  It is very likely that some static fields are used there.  Also, `challengeRemaining` is declared, defined and not used in the loop.